# Как отсортировать строки по буквам и взять только одну букву без повтора, при этом вернуть самую длинную строку?

Tags: javascript

Возьмем 2 строки s1 и s2, содержащие только буквы от a до z.
Вернуть новую отсортированную строку, как можно более длинную,
содержащую отдельные буквы - каждая взятая только один раз - исходящая из s1 или s2.

Мой код:

```
function longest(s1, s2) {
    let result = '';
    const str = s1.length > s2.length ? s1 : s2;

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
        if (result.indexOf(str[i]) < 0) {
            result += str[i];
        }
    }
    return result.split('').sort().join('');
}

console.log(longest("loopingisfunbutdangerous", "lessdangerousthancoding"));
```

Ожидаю на выходе получить  отсортированную строку : "abcdefghilnoprstu"
А, по факту почему-то получаю -->>> "abdefgilnoprstu" БЕЗ двух букв "c" и "h" ;
Почему они отбрасываться не могу понять и как сделать чтобы этого не происходило???
Подскажите где ошибка или какую проверку еще надо сделать!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка - Вы рассмaтриваете буквы только из одной строки.

```js
function longest(s1, s2) {
  return Array.from(new Set((s1 + s2).split(''))).sort().join('');
}

const result = longest("loopingisfunbutdangerous", "lessdangerousthancoding");
console.log(result.length, result);
```

Comment: Почему из одной строки?! Я ведь  передаю в функцию два аргумента?
Или из тернарника возвращается, только одна строка и далее цикл проходиться только по этой строке и все или как???
Объясните более расширенно.

Comment: @SergGorelikov "Я ведь передаю в функцию два аргумента?" - хоть двадцать два. Чему равно значение переменной `str` (`console.log(str);`)? Нужно говорить "Пожалуйста, объясните ...".